# Share environments through diferent projects

Tags: yaml, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to share environments through diferent projects in devops. Something similar as service connections that has a feature in the security section, to share conecctions between diferent projects.

As far as I know this is not possible. But I would like to know if somebody has think in some kind of workaround or good alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops ?

Comment: yes, correct. how can i share across projects, thoose features